# Customize elastislide slider to move one item at a time

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using this thumbnail slider, but I want to customize this slider to move only one image at a time. Please have a look at the given link - [ElastiSlide](http://tympanus.net/Development/Elastislide/index.html) and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

jquery.elastislide.js v1.1.0
change line 590 `var amount = this.fitCount * itemSpace;` to `var amount = itemSpace;`